# Java 2d Array Wrong Coordinate With Tiles

Tags: java, swing, tile

I'm currently developing a Java rpg game. I'm at early stages, trying to figure out the game engine, notably the tiling mechaniques. The game is indeed composed of tiling, and the the player is static while the background moves. I've encountered a big problem concerning 2d arrays for collision detection. Here is the code (please excuse the length):

```
package java4k;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Christophe
 */
public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    public Image dbImage;
    public Graphics dbGraphics;

    //Move Variables
    int x = 320,y = 240, xDirection, yDirection;

    //Sprites
    BufferedImage spriteSheet;

    //Lists for sprite sheet: 1 = STILL; 2 = MOVING_1; 3 = MOVING_2
    BufferedImage[] ARCHER_NORTH = new BufferedImage[4];
    BufferedImage[] ARCHER_SOUTH = new BufferedImage[4];
    BufferedImage[] ARCHER_EAST = new BufferedImage[4];
    BufferedImage[] ARCHER_WEST = new BufferedImage[4];

    Image[] TILE = new Image[4];

    //Animation Variables
    int currentFrame = 0, framePeriod = 150;
    long frameTicker = 0l;
    Boolean still = true;
    Boolean MOVING_NORTH = false, MOVING_SOUTH = false, MOVING_EAST = false, MOVING_WEST = false;

    BufferedImage player = ARCHER_SOUTH[0];

    //World Tile Variables
    //20 X 15 = 300 tiles 
    Rectangle[][] blocks = new Rectangle[20][15];
    Image[][] blockImg = new Image[20][15];
    int tileX = 0, tileY = 0;
    Random r = new Random();

    Rectangle playerRect = new Rectangle(x+4,y+20,32,20);
    Rectangle checkRect;

    //Map Navigation
    static final byte PAN_UP = 0, PAN_DOWN  = 1, PAN_LEFT = 2, PAN_RIGHT = 3;



    public Main(){

        this.setTitle("JAVA4K");
        this.setSize(640,505);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        addKeyListener(new AL());

        TILE[0] = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Java4k/src/java4k/TILE_GRASS_1.png").getImage();
        TILE[1] = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Java4k/src/java4k/TILE_GRASS_2.png").getImage();
        TILE[2] = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Java4k/src/java4k/TILE_GRASS_3.png").getImage();
        TILE[3] = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Java4k/src/java4k/TILE_WATER_1.png").getImage();

        loadTiles();

        init();
    }

    //First called to store image tiles in blockImg[][] and tile rectangles in blocks[][]
    private void loadTiles(){
        tileX = tileY = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){

                if(tileX>=640){
                    tileX = 0;
                    tileY += 32;
                }
                blockImg[i][j] = TILE[r.nextInt(4)];
                blocks[i][j] = new Rectangle(tileX, tileY, 32, 32);
                tileX += 32;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(blocks[2][0]);
    }

    //collision detection
    public boolean collide(Rectangle in)
    {
        for (int y = (int)((in.y) / 32)-1; y <= (int)((in.y+in.height) / 32)+1; y++){
            for (int x = (int)((in.x) / 32)-1; x <= (int)((in.x+in.width) / 32)+1; x++){
                if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < 32 && y < 32){
                    if (blockImg[x][y] != null)
                    {
                        checkRect.setBounds(x*32,y*32, 32, 32);
                        if (in.intersects(checkRect))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

      return false;
    }

    //Key Listener
    public class AL extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

            int keyInput = e.getKeyCode();
            still = false;
            if(keyInput == e.VK_LEFT){

                navigateMap(PAN_RIGHT);
                MOVING_WEST = true;

            }if(keyInput == e.VK_RIGHT){

                navigateMap(PAN_LEFT);
                MOVING_EAST = true;

            }if(keyInput == e.VK_UP){

                navigateMap(PAN_DOWN);
                MOVING_NORTH = true;

            }if(keyInput == e.VK_DOWN){

                navigateMap(PAN_UP);
                MOVING_SOUTH = true;
            }
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

            int keyInput = e.getKeyCode();
            setXDirection(0);
            setYDirection(0);
            still = true;
            MOVING_SOUTH  = false;
            MOVING_NORTH = MOVING_SOUTH = MOVING_EAST = MOVING_WEST = false;
            if(keyInput == e.VK_LEFT){

                player = ARCHER_WEST[0];

            }if(keyInput == e.VK_RIGHT){

                player = ARCHER_EAST[0];

            }if(keyInput == e.VK_UP){

                player = ARCHER_NORTH[0];

            }if(keyInput == e.VK_DOWN){

                player = ARCHER_SOUTH[0];
            }
        }
    }


    public void moveMap(){

        for(Rectangle[] r : blocks){
            for(Rectangle r2 : r){
                r2.x += xDirection;
                r2.y += yDirection;
            }
        }    
    }


    public void navigateMap(byte pan){
        switch(pan){
            default:
                System.out.println("Unrecognized pan!");
                break;
            case PAN_UP:
                setYDirection(-1);
                break;
            case PAN_DOWN:
                setYDirection(+1);
                break;
            case PAN_LEFT:
                setXDirection(-1);
                break;
            case PAN_RIGHT:
                setXDirection(+1);
                break;
        }
    }


    //Animation Update
    public void update(long gameTime) {

        if (gameTime > frameTicker + framePeriod) {
            frameTicker = gameTime;
            currentFrame++;
            if (currentFrame >= 4) {
                currentFrame = 0;
            }
        }
        if(MOVING_NORTH) player = ARCHER_NORTH[currentFrame];
        if(MOVING_SOUTH) player = ARCHER_SOUTH[currentFrame];
        if(MOVING_EAST) player = ARCHER_EAST[currentFrame];
        if(MOVING_WEST) player = ARCHER_WEST[currentFrame];
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xdir){

        xDirection = xdir;
    }

    public void setYDirection(int ydir){

        yDirection = ydir;
    }


    //Method to get sprites
    public BufferedImage grabSprite(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        BufferedImage sprite = spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
        return sprite;
    }

    private void init(){    
        spriteSheet = null;
        try {
            spriteSheet = loadImage("ARCHER_SPRITESHEET.png");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            ARCHER_NORTH[i] = grabSprite(i*16, 16, 16,16);
            ARCHER_SOUTH[i] = grabSprite(i*16, 0, 16, 16);
            ARCHER_EAST[i] = grabSprite(i*16, 32, 16, 16);
            ARCHER_WEST[i] = grabSprite(i*16, 48, 16, 16);
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String pathRelativeToThis) throws IOException{

        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(pathRelativeToThis);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        return img;
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){

        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbGraphics = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbGraphics);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 25, this);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        requestFocus();

        //Draws tiles and rectangular boundaries for debugging
        for(int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < 15; b++){
                if(blockImg[a][b] != null && blocks[a][b] != null){
                    g.drawImage(blockImg[a][b], blocks[a][b].x, blocks[a][b].y, 32, 32, null);
                    g.drawRect(blocks[a][b].x, blocks[a][b].y, 32, 32);
                } 
            }
        }   

        //Draw player and rectangular boundary for collision detection
        g.drawRect(playerRect.x, playerRect.y, playerRect.width, playerRect.height);
        g.drawImage(player, x, y, 40, 40, null);
        repaint();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                moveMap();
                if(!still) update(System.currentTimeMillis());
                Thread.sleep(13);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("RUNTIME ERROR: " + e);
        }    
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

        //Threads
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(main);
        thread1.start();
    }
}
```

My error is as follows: if I were to call an object from blocks[][] (a 2d array that stores rectangles for collision 
detection purposes) it would give me something totally different. For example, I take `blocks[0][0]` (note that each tile is a 32 pixel square). The coordinates of this rectangle would be `0,0`. However, if I were to draw blocks[1][0], which would logically give me `(32;0)`, it would return `(480;0)`. I've almost pulled my hair out trying to find the cause of 
this, which i'm guessing is due to `blocks[].x` being changed somewhere, but I can't find where. I've tried printing out every value of `blocks[][]` in the draw method to see where the probleme is, and for some reason, in loadTiles() everything is fine and all of a sudden everything is messed up. Thank you in advance for your help, and I hope I've provided enough information :)!

Comment: are you interpreting blocks[][] as blocks[x][y] or blocks[y][x]?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mistake in loadTiles.

you are looping through each x, and for each x:
you are looping through each y, and for each y:
set blocks[x][y] to tileX, tileY
tileX += 32;

Since you are looping through y in the second loop, shouldn't that be
tileY += 32;

or:

```
//First called to store image tiles in blockImg[][] and tile rectangles in blocks[][]
private void loadTiles(){
    tileX = tileY = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        tileX = 32 * i;
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){

            tyleY = 32 * j;

            blockImg[i][j] = TILE[r.nextInt(4)];
            blocks[i][j] = new Rectangle(tileX, tileY, 32, 32);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(blocks[2][0]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your suggestion! :) I slightly modifed the code, and made the X increment outside of the 1st for loop, while resetting Y at the same place.